# MySQL sum() and group by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   corporation.id, expense.year, expense.type, SUM(Expense.amount) as sum 
FROM 
   expenses 
LEFT JOIN
   corporation ON expense.corporation_id = corporation.id
LEFT JOIN
   project ON expense.project_id = project.id
WHERE
   project.id = XYZ
GROUP BY
   corporation.name, corporation.id, expense.year
ORDER BY
   sum DESC;
```

MySQL now orders this by `sum` for the latest expense.year, but I'd like it to order by `sum` of all years (i.e. like a query without `GROUP BY (...) expense.year`). Is this possible?

Comment: I can't be bothered to setup test tables for this in MySQL - Can you do something with `WITH ROLLUP` though?

Comment: WITH ROLLUP excludes ORDER BY, unfortunately...

Comment: Ah, sorry if I sent you on a wild goose chase!

Answer (score 0):

Sum is a single value so you can get it using one query. And get other data in seperate query. or use a sub query at `SUM(...) as sum`